# Vue.js remove item on delete

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I have list below and when i delete my items they will not be removed from my list unless i refresh the page.

`List`

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="school in schools" v-bind:key="school.id">
        <td>{{ school.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ school.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <button
            class="btn btn-danger"
            v-on:click="deleteSchool(school.id)">
            Delete
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

`Delete method`

```
deleteSchool(id)
{
  let uri = `http://localhost/schools/${id}`;
  this.axios.delete(uri);
  this.schools.splice(id, 1);
}
```

**Any idea?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use index it 's like a key to splice an item from the list

```
<tbody>
    <tr v-for="(school,index) in schools" v-bind:key="school.id">
        <td>{{ school.id }}</td>
        <td>{{ school.name }}</td>
        <td>
            <button
            class="btn btn-danger"
            v-on:click="deleteSchool(school.id,index)">
            Delete
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

```
deleteSchool(id,index)
{
  let uri = `http://localhost/schools/${id}`;
  this.axios.delete(uri);
  this.schools.splice(index, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using ES6, it could also be done like this, with `findIndex()`.

```
<tbody>
  <tr v-for="school in schools" :key="school.id">
    <td>{{ school.id }}</td>
    <td>{{ school.name }}</td>
    <td>
      <button
        class="btn btn-danger"
        @click="deleteSchool(school.id)">
        Delete
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

---

```
methods: {
  deleteSchool(id) {
    const uri = `http://localhost/schools/${id}`;

    this.axios.delete(uri);

    const schoolIndex = this.schools.findIndex(school => school.id === id);

    this.schools.splice(schoolIndex, 1);
  }
}
```